# Graphql fetch api not returning data

Tags: javascript, graphql, next.js, fetch

I am learning Next.js and GraphQL. I have the following code.

I am trying to return the following query

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
   const client = new ApolloClient({
      uri: "https://data.objkt.com/graphiql/",
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
   })

   const{data} = await client.query({
      query: gql`
         query{
           fa2_by_pk(contract: "KT1LHHLso8zQWQWg1HUukajdxxbkGfNoHjh6") {
             floor_price
           }
         }
      `
   });
   return {
     props: {
       c: data.fa2_by_pk.floor_price,
    }
  }
```

}

```
export default function Home(c) {
   console.log(c);
```

However I do not seem to be getting the data back. This is what I see

```
{}
  [[Prototype]]: Object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that endpoint a graphiql interface endpoint or the actual graphql endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint as I visit it now is an interactive igraphql endpoint.  Making the same request and looking at the network request, the endpoint you should be using is

https://data.objkt.com/v1/graphql

I can't speak to what authentication you may require.